# how to use ffmpeg in python to record a specific window with system audio without command line and cleanly stop it

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, subprocess, pyinstaller

I'm working in an application that is capturing specific window from my desktop and grabbing the system audio, it application is packaged with pyinstaller with --windowed parameter, when I start to capture video it work perfectly and in a debbug execution it stop cleanly, but when I run it from the packaged file, the ffmpeg process never stop. I'm using subprocess.popen to launch ffmpeg by this way:

```
command = ['ffmpeg','-f', 'dshow', '-i', f'audio={device}', '-f', 'gdigrab', '-framerate', '30', '-i', f'title={device_model}', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'slower', '-crf', '22', f'{file_path}']
subprocess.Popen(comando,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
```